# Delete button for each mysql result

Tags: php, mysql, delete-row

I am a beginner in PHP. I was trying to create a password manager using PHP and MySQL. But I am having trouble at this point:

```
<?php
require 'dbconnect.php';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM pmanager";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$con);
if (!$result) die ("Database access failed: " . mysql_error());
$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
//Views results from existing rows
   for ($j = 0 ; $j < $rows ; ++$j)
    {
        echo 'Account: ' . mysql_result($result,$j,'account') . '<br />';
        echo 'E-mail: ' . mysql_result($result,$j,'email') . '<br />';
        echo 'Username: ' . mysql_result($result,$j,'uname') . '<br />';
        echo 'Password: ' . mysql_result($result,$j,'pword') . '<br />'; ?>
        <form method="post"> <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo mysql_result($result, $j, 'id'); ?> " /><input type="submit" name="del" value="Delete" /> </form>
 <?php }
if(isset($_POST['del']))
    {
       $sql1 = "DELETE FROM pmanager WHERE id = " . $_POST['id'];
       if(mysql_query($sql1,$con))
       {
          echo 'Deleted';
       }
       else
           echo 'Error: '.mysql_error();
    }
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Suppose there are two rows in the table "pmanager" containing two Account (e.g. FB, Twitter). And after executing the code there will be a delete button for each of the accounts. Now what can I do to this button click event so that the desired account can be deleted?

This is my first question in StackOverflow :)

Comment: just do a "DELETE FROM pmanager WHERE <column> = <value>", just change the <variables> to fit your needs. I'd also do the delete before running the select query, that way the list will show the values that are left.

Comment: Try not to do things like this: `$sql1 = "DELETE FROM pmanager WHERE id = " . $_POST['id'];`

Comment: @atx what should I do instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the most rudimentary forms you can create a hidden field in your mini form with the record id. Then you can capture the id from the delete script and execute the code to delete the record.

```
<form method="post"> <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo mysql_result($result, $j, 'id'); ?> " /><input type="submit" name="del" value="Delete" /> </form>
```

Comment: @DevZero, Thanks bro, I did what you wanted me to do, but please take a look and tell me what's wrong: :(

[Error](http://img9.imageshack.us/img9/3569/kw3.png)

Comment: @DevZero Thanks. Could you please update again with this line edited:

`echo '<form method="post"> <input type="submit" name="del" value="Delete" /> </form>';`

[And here is the error message](http://img9.imageshack.us/img9/3569/kw3.png)

Comment: @Don updated don't use echo in that statement just bring palin easier that way

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<form method="post"> <input type="submit" name="del" value="Delete" /> </form>';
```

In this part edit the echo code

```
'<form method="post"><input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo mysql_result($result, $j, 'id'); ?> " /> <input type="submit" name="del" value="Delete" /> </form>';
```

AND then you can

```
 if(isset($_POST['del']))
    {
       //What can I do here?
       $id=$_POST['del'];
       $sql='DELETE FROM pmanager WHERE id='.$id
    }
```

Comment: Hi @mehman-bashirov Thank you for your reply. I edited the code, but there is an error. Would you please take a look at this:

[ErrorMessage](http://img9.imageshack.us/img9/3569/kw3.png)

Comment: Yes mistake is in echo ;                  echo    '<form method="post"><input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.mysql_result($result, $j, 'id').'" /> <input type="submit" name="del" value="Delete" /> </form>';